# ng build --prod fails after upgrade from Angular2 to Angular4

Tags: typescript, npm, angular-cli, angular

After *upgrading* my **Angular2** project to **Angular4** using:

```
npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save
```

I receive the following error when I use `ng build --prod`:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'D:\workspace\MyProject\src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

Without the `--prod` flag I don't get any errors. There are a few similar questions on stackoverflow but without any accepted answers and not related with the upgrade to Angular4. 
Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.0.5",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "ng2-adal": "^0.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.46",
    "@types/node": "~7.0.11",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0"
  }
}
```

**Edit**. Here is a *project.json* created with `ng new` and the new CLI:

```
{
  "name": "mypro",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How does your `package.json` compare to one from `ng new` with your version of the CLI?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Good point, I already tried to play with the versions but keep getting the same error message. I will post the package.json created with ng new with the new CLI version.

Comment: Does the build work when you try this: `ng build --prod --aot false`?

Comment: @R.Richards Yes, the build work without error if I add the `--aot false` parameter. Any idea whats going wrong?

Comment: The default build compile mode now is AOT compilation, despite what the wiki might say on angular.io. You have to go through some extra steps in your code to get AOT to work, or avoid it by setting the flag to false. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html. When I have run into issues with AOT, I usually get better error messages than what you show. At least a component name, or something.

Comment: @R.Richards Thank you, at least I have an indication now. I will read the aot-compiler doc you posted within your comment and try to set it up correctly. You might add an answer to my question, I will probably accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get your application to build, but you will more than likely need to include the `--aot false` parameter along with `--prod` in order for it to work. See below.

`ng build --prod --aot false`

The default production build compile mode is AOT compilation now. You have to go through some extra steps in your code to get AOT to work, or avoid it by setting the flag to false. The [AOT Cookbook](http://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) should be of some help.

The GitHub [wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build) for `ng build` indicates that the default value for the `--aot` flag is false, but that doesn't seem to be the case. `ng build --help` doesn't show that there is a default value. Using the flag shows/proves that the default is true.

When I have run into issues with AOT, I usually get better error messages than what you show in your question; at least a component name, or something that tells me where to look. Many of what I end up seeing in my errors are things like not explicitly declaring a variable in a component. JIT doesn't care about that, but AOT doesn't like it at all.

Hope this helps you out.